# trying to move a div before another div without screwing up php that I do not understand :)

Tags: php

I am a designer/front-end developer but I have to move the div with a class of "span-4" before the div with a class of "span-20." The developer who wrote the php is not available to ask how to not mess up his php markup.

Thank you in advance for any help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>THRIVE</title>
   <?php include("header.php"); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="container">   
        <div id="thumbnails" class="span-20 last">
        <?php
            $accessoriesDir = "images/accessories/";
            $collectionCount = 1;
            while(is_dir($accessoriesDir . $collectionCount . "/"))
            {
                $collection_dir = $accessoriesDir . $collectionCount . "/";
                if ($season_dh = opendir($collection_dir)) 
                {   
                    $accsArray = array();
                    $accsCount = 0;
                    while (($accessoryFolder = readdir($season_dh)) !== false)
                    {
                        if(filetype($collection_dir . $accessoryFolder) == "dir" && strlen($accessoryFolder) > 2)
                            $accsArray[$accsCount++] = $accessoryFolder;
                    }
                    closedir($season_dh);
                    ?>
                    <div id="collection<?php echo $collectionCount?>" class="thumbsHolder <?php if($collectionCount !== 1) echo 'hidden'?>">

                    <div class="cats span-4">
                        <?php
                            foreach($accsArray as $index => $accessory)
                            {
                                $class = "accessory-tab";
                                if($index == 0)
                                {
                                    $class .= " selected";
                                }
                                echo "<a id='".strtolower($accessory)."-tab' class='".$class."'>".$accessory."</a><br/>";
                            }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    foreach($accsArray as $index => $accessory)
                    {
                        ?>
                        <div id="<?php echo strtolower($accessory);?>-view" class="view <?php if($index != 0) echo 'hidden';?>">
                        <?php
                        $imageCount = 0;
                        $accessoryDir = $collection_dir.$accessory."/";
                        $dh = opendir($accessoryDir);
                        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false && $imageCount < 8) 
                        {
                            if(filetype($accessoryDir . $file) == "file" && substr($file, -4) == ".jpg")
                            {
                            ?>
                                <div class="thumbnailExpander <?php if($imageCount % 2 !== 0)echo 'expandLeft';?> <?php if($imageCount >= 4)echo 'bottom';?>" 
                                    style="left:<?php echo ($imageCount % 4) * (317-132) ?>px;top:<?php echo 110+((132+53)*intval($imageCount/4));?>px;">
                                    <!--div class="thumbAnchor"-->
                                        <img src="<?php echo $accessoryDir . $file ?>" style=""/>
                                    <!--/div-->
                                </div>
                            <?php
                                $imageCount++;
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                        </div><!-- #accessory-view -->
                        <?php
                        closedir($dh);
                    }
                    ?>
                    </div><!-- .thumbsHolder -->
                    <?php
                }
                $collectionCount++;
            }
        ?>
        </div><!-- #thumbnails -->

        <?php include("nav.php"); ?>
        <div id="debug" style="color:white"></div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank god the developer isn't around anymore, that's vomit inducing.  Separating business logic from presentation logic would fix this.

Comment: separating business logic from presentation is not the only issue to be discussed in that example XD. long time since i saw someone to be mad enough to do something like a webshop based purely on the filesystem.

Comment: this is dailyWTF worthy stuff right here

Comment: +1 simply because of super old-school php4 type stuff :) sorry guys!

Answer (score 4):

Refactoring this code so that the span-4 is displayed first is not going to be an easy task. It's going to be near impossible (and not advisable) if you have no PHP experience.

I would suggest that you use CSS to move the span-4 element around on the displayed page. That way you'll not need to touch the PHP. Even better; when the PHP developer returns get them to refactor this so that the display code is not entwined with the business logic (it's a horrible practice that makes questions like this impossible to answer).

Hope that helps some.

Comment: after he refactored it; shoot him!

Comment: you either get the programmer to change it, get your hands dirty and learn php and try to work it out or you get someone to do it for you. This is depending on the agreements with your client and how much more he is willing to spend.

Answer (score 0):

Try these two steps:

(1) Cut everything from the first `<?php` line after span-20 all the way down to the closing  tag of the span-4... and paste it above the span-20 div. This includes all the garbage + the span-4 div in its entirety.

(2) In the code you just pasted, find this line:

```
<div id="collection<?php echo $collectionCount?>" class="thumbsHolder <?php if($collectionCount !== 1) echo 'hidden'?>">
```

... and cut & paste it back in the space it where came from.

That should work for you, unless I need to get my eyes checked.

EDIT: There's a chance it won't work, depending on whether the span-4 really needs to be a child of #collection. If that's the case, you'll need to tuck into the CSS and separate the two, or somehow carry the parent id out with the span-4.